# How to change date format to German?

Tags: formatting, datetime, german

I use the `\today` comment, then it produces `26th February`. However in my context, I want `26ten Februar`. How can I change that?

Comment: Actually »[babel](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel)« with its language option `ngerman` should already do the trick. But you can also have a look at »[isodate](http://ctan.org/pkg/isodate)«. For more than these assumptions you should provide a *self-contained* and [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228).

Comment: seems \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} does not work for me.

Comment: @Ginger You should post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), so people can determine what is not working for you...

Comment: There is also package datetime.

Comment: The question was already answered, but as a native German speaker I have to say, that it is really unusual to write '26ten' or anything which resembles that. It should be written '26. Februar'.

Comment: It seems that you didn't even bother to provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) (→ -1)

Answer (score 20):

Try with the `datetime` package, by defining a new date format:

```
\newdateformat{myformat}{\THEDAY{ten }\monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{datetime}

\newdateformat{myformat}{\THEDAY{ten }\monthname[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}

\begin{document}

\myformat\today

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

If you can't load `babel` with the language `ngerman`, you can however load `datetime` as

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}
```

and define the date format as

```
\newdateformat{myformat}{\THEDAY{ten }\monthnamengerman[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{datetime}

\newdateformat{myformat}{\THEDAY{ten }\monthnamengerman[\THEMONTH], \THEYEAR}

\begin{document}

\myformat\today

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks@karlkoeller, but because i already have \usepackage[english]{babel}, then i cannot add \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}. If I do this\PassOptionsToPackage{english,ngerman}{babel}, Februry is still in English.

Comment: @Ginger Instead of \PassOptionToPackage, use `\selectlanguage{ngerman}` immediately after `\begin{document}` -

Comment: @Ginger See the edited answer.

Comment: @Ginger: Although this seems to answer the question, this is formally completely wrong (as already mentioned in the comments to the questions). In German we don't write dates in this way. Mark my words!